# Odd containers appearing when I click on any element on my page. React/SCSS/React-Hook-Form

Tags: reactjs, forms, sass, react-hook-form

[image]I just implemented a simple login form. Whenever I click on any of the elements on the form, there is a weird unidentified container appearing in the background. It's odd because it seems to have the same glassmorphism effect as my login container. But the unidentified container size is just random and varies depending on what element I am clicking on.
I am using React with SCSS and using React-Hook-Forms for the login.

Login.jsx

```js
const LoginForm = ({ login }) => {
  const [focused, setfocused] = useState("");

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <motion.input
        className="text-input"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        ref={register}
      ></motion.input>
      <motion.input
        className="text-input"
        name="password"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        ref={register}
      ></motion.input>
      <motion.input className="submit-button" type="submit" value="Login" />
      <h3>
        New student?{" "}
        <Link className="register-link" to="/register">
          Register here!
        </Link>
      </h3>
    </form>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

```css
form {
    @include flex(flex-start, center, column);
    height: auto;
    min-width: 450px;
    padding: 100px 50px;

    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(218, 216, 216, 0.37);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    
    h1 {
        @include primary-font($headerSize, $headerWeight);
        color: $faintWhite;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        &:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            height: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            background: $faintWhite;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
    }
    .text-input {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        color: $faintWhite;
        @include primary-font(1rem, 500);

        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(218, 216, 216, 0.37);
        backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);

        &::placeholder {
            color: $faintWhite;
            @include primary-font(1rem, 500);
        }
    }
    .submit-button {
        @include primary-font(1.4rem, 600);
        color: #505050;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        margin: 5px 0 30px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 32px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        border: none;
    }
    h3 {
        @include primary-font(1rem, 500);
        color: $faintWhite;
        .register-link {
            @include primary-font(1rem, 600);
            color: $faintWhite;
        }
    }
}
```

Above is SCSS

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating backdrop-filter solved the issue.
"The backdrop-filter CSS property lets you apply graphical effects such as blurring or color shifting to the area **behind an element**."
I suppose this had something to do with the issue.